# Qt - multimedia button events not being forwarded to the OS

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5.4

I've created a default Qt application in Visual Studio 2013 with Qt add-in. There's no event filter. All my multimedia button events are not being forwarded to Windows. I've tried to override the `QMainWindow::event` and see the output:

```
bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *event)
{
    cout << event->type() << endl;

    return QMainWindow::event(event);
}
```

Press:

```
51 - QEvent::ShortcutOverride
51 - QEvent::ShortcutOverride
6  - QEvent::KeyPress
```

Release:

```
7  - QEvent::KeyRelease
```

They are registered by the Qt application. What's blocking them?

I also have a notebook with multimedia buttons separated from function keys and they all work except volume up and volume down buttons. A notification (from driver) pops up on key-down, but the volume doesn't change as I'm holding the button down.

Comment: There's quite a big gap between the OS and your application. All that you're telling us is that a presumably focused window in your program doesn't see the multimedia key press events. This doesn't mean Windows doesn't get to see them.